# vim select paragraph -- how to redefine paragraph boundaries?

Tags: vim

In vim, vip selects "inner paragraph" :help v_ip, 
however it is of limited use.

vim paragraph boundary is hard coded, a
paragraph is separated by 2 or more blank lines.
:help paragraph

Some archaic marcos like .IP,  also seem to be supported as 
paragraph separators, but it is all hard coded.

I want to specify my own paragraph separators to easily
select paragraphs of text in vim.

Like perl in paragraph mode using an regexp splitter.

I tried setting paragraphs to be delimited by blank lines or braces:
:set paragraph+={ cpoptions+={
but does NOT work as documented, 
braces are ignored by 'vip' selection command.

The solution I want should work for all paragraphs commands
like vip, vap, dip, dap, `{,`}.

Comment: I don't think vim currently supports what you want.  Is there a reason you don't want to use `i{`?

Answer (score 2):

Note how you can map operators, so you won't have to remap vip or vap (you could map aH to your movement operation - and all of the following work magically using your selections:

```
 daH
 vaHy
 d2aH
```

etc

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's an option for you, but you can change paragraph delimiting in certain way by including the 'w' flag in 'formatoptions'. Check out help for 'fo-table' to read more.  Basically it makes it so that lines ending in a space are like 'soft returns' and lines ending in a non-space character mark the end of paragraphs.  Empty lines are not markers at all in this case.  The 'w' formation flag does work with all vip, vap, etc., if I recall.

If that isn't going to do the trick for you, then I suggest remapping the vip, vap, etc. sequences to a custom function of your own.  That way you can set it up to select things exactly as you want.

Answer (score 0):

See `:help paragraphs`.

```
'paragraphs' 'para'     string  (default "IPLPPPQPP TPHPLIPpLpItpplpipbp")
                    global
    Specifies the nroff macros that separate paragraphs.  These are pairs
    of two letters (see object-motions).
```